# Mutually exclusive radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Here is a small code snippet I wrote that I feel is pretty naive. I copied the code directly from my project and renamed some ID/class names.

I'd like to know how you could help to improve/refactor the code. `radiobox1` and `radiobox2` form a pair, and `radiobox3` and `radiobox4` form another pair - they're both mutually exclusive - which means select `radiobox1` then `radiobox2` is disabled, and vice versa. Then I will load the data in terms of the user's selection combination. In total, there are 4 selection combinations.

```
var viz = (function () {
    var config = {
        width: 960,
        height:600,
        big: true,
        small: true,
        index: 0
    };

    var emptyGraph = function () {
        if (!$('#graph').is(':empty')) {
            $("#graph").empty();
        }
    };

    var bind = function () {
        $("#radiobox1").change(function () {
           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               emptyGraph();
               $("#radiobox2").prop("checked", false);
               config.small = true;
               loader.loadData(config);
           }
        });

        $("#radiobox2").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                emptyGraph();
                $("#radiobox1").prop("checked", false);
                config.small = false;
                loader.loadData(config);

            }
        });

        $("#radiobox3").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                emptyGraph();
                $("#radiobox4").prop("checked", false);
                config.big = true;
                loader.loadData(config);
            }
        });


        $("#radiobox4").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                emptyGraph();
                $("#radiobox3").prop("checked", false);
                config.big = false;
                config.index = 1;
                loader.loadData(config);
            }
        });

    };

    return {
        init: bind,
    }

})();
```

Comment: Would you mind including the corresponding HTML as well, so that we can better understand what it's doing? (You can use Ctrl-M in the editor to make a live demo.)

Comment: **Radio** buttons can already be mutually exclusive - just give the `input`'s the same `name` (in your case, one name for a pair and another for the other) and the browser will make sure that only one is selected. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a radio button isn't even the input you want to use: your code suggests that these two states are either true or false, which semantically fits the function of a `checkbox`. Therefore your bind function could look like this:

```
var bind = function () {
    $("#checkbox1").change(function () {
       emptyGraph();
       config.small = $(this).is(':checked');
       loader.loadData(config);
    });

    $("#checkbox2").change(function () {
        emptyGraph();
        config.big = $(this).is(':checked');
        loader.loadData(config);
    });
};
```

---

Going one step further, because the two controls are behaving so similarly, you could combine them:

```
var bind = function () {
    $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').change(function () {
       emptyGraph();
       config.small = $('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
       config.big = $('#checkbox2').is(':checked');
       loader.loadData(config);
    });
};
```

---

If for whatever reason (e.g., UX concerns) you cannot use checkboxes instead of radio buttons, [@Jonathan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/38974/jonathan)'s answer solves mutual exclusivity from the HTML side of things. Your binding code could then be as simple as follows:

```
var bind = function () {
    $('#radiobox1, #radiobox2, #radiobox3, #radiobox4').change(function () {
       emptyGraph();
       config.small = $('#radiobox1').is(':checked');
       config.big = $('#radiobox3').is(':checked');
       loader.loadData(config);
    });
};
```

I just noticed that `radiobox4`'s change function changes the config's index property. In this case, you'll need to do additional logic inside the function:

```
var bind = function () {
    $('#radiobox1, #radiobox2, #radiobox3, #radiobox4').change(function () {
        emptyGraph();
        config.small = $('#radiobox1').is(':checked');
        if($('#radiobox3').is(':checked')) {
            config.big = true;
        } else {
            config.big = false;
            config.index = 1;
        }
        loader.loadData(config);
    });
};
```

Comment: I like your comment, especially suggest me to combine those two methods together. However I think if we combine them, we miss one thing - mutually exclusive. For example, as long as "checkbox2" is checked, "checkbox1" should be unchecked. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: `checkbox1` is functionally the same as `radiobox1` and `radiobox2`, and `checkbox2` is functionally the same as `radiobox3` and `radiobox4`. The mutual exclusion is fulfilled by the fact that a checkbox cannot be both checked and unchecked. As per your scenario, `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` should not be mutually exclusive from each other.

Comment: @catlovespurple See my updated answer if you want to keep radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I want! And after reading your previous post(the checkbox one) I come up with the same solution as you just posted! so the answer is granted to you!

Answer (score 3):

Radio buttons already group together using the `name` attribute. I suggest throwing away the code.

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="female">Female<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="1">Active<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="0">Inactive
```

Comment: yes! this is what I want, mutually exclusive radio button groups in html. However, one thing here is that, I have to refactor the JS code in order to load the right data in terms of user selection. Any comments/improvements on my JS code?